# Unknown top and bottom padding in panels

Tags: css, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm using the panels module in drupal 7. I'm having some problem with the css in panels. I've removed the top and bottom padding in my custom css but there still appears to be some padding. How can I remove it? I have give the id "leftpane" and made the following CSS

```
#leftpane {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    background:#17532E;
    border-radius:17px;
    float: left;
    }
```

How do I remove the unknown top and bottom padding?

Comment: try with "!important" in css or select proper hierarchy of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clear cache if you are using any.

You can also try setting 'no markup at all' setting in your pane style.